# Rails.fire unable to submit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, rails-ujs

I want to submit a remote form using JS and I am using Rails `5.2.0`.

The form looks like below:

```
<form class="new_post" id="my_form" action="/posts" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="UxvP0R6bSbbzwuXyTj/hTCvf6Tmdzqr1j5mQVy9ZaaoBBd5LhkS3o4y3iXKWLfZzQ0pgATbOmvh8/cj2YAXy3Q==">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="title">Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="post[title]" id="post_title">
  </div>
</form>
```

As per https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546 , I should be able to submit a form using `Rails.fire($('#my_form')[0], 'submit');` .

However in my case the above line is simply returning `false`, hence it is not submitting the form.

> The above code was working just fine when I was using Turbolinks 5. It has stopped working when I removed Turbolinks from the application.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the `rails-ujs`, got to know the issue is being created by [pace.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HubSpot/pace/v0.5.3/pace.min.js) which I have added to the project.

Once I removed it, everything started working fine.